# Go strings.Contains() 2x slower than Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, performance, go, yara

Am converting a text pattern scanner from Python3 to Go1.10, but am surprised it is actually 2 times slower. Upon profiling, the culprit is in `strings.Contains()`. See the simple benchmarks below. Did I miss anything? Could you recommend a faster pattern search algorithm for Go that would perform better in this case? I'm not bothered about startup time, the same pattern will be used to scan millions of files.

Py3 benchmark:

```
import time
import re

RUNS = 10000

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('data.php') as fh:
        testString = fh.read()

    def do():
        return "576ad4f370014dfb1d0f17b0e6855f22" in testString

    start = time.time()
    for i in range(RUNS):
        _ = do()
    duration = time.time() - start
    print("Python: %.2fs" % duration)
```

Go1.10 benchmark:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

const (
    runs = 10000
)

func main() {
    fname := "data.php"
    testdata := readFile(fname)
    needle := "576ad4f370014dfb1d0f17b0e6855f22"
    start := time.Now()

    for i := 0; i < runs; i++ {
        _ = strings.Contains(testdata, needle)

    }
    duration := time.Now().Sub(start)
    fmt.Printf("Go: %.2fs\n", duration.Seconds())
}

func readFile(fname string) string {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fname)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return string(data)
}
```

`data.php` is a 528KB file that can be [found here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gwillem/magento-malware-scanner/master/corpus/backend/3f34f51c981a9ddcfb0f41815c7dad49).

Output:

```
Go:     1.98s
Python: 0.84s
```

Comment: Please use the benchmark framework offered by package `testing` in Go. (BTW I doubt you will find something more optimized than strings.Contains or byte.Contains).

Comment: The needle is exactly 32-byte long. It means it gets asm optimization on 64-bit machines but not on 32-bit ones. Though I am amazed at Python3's speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done more benchmarking with various string search implementations that I found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm), such as:

- https://github.com/cloudflare/ahocorasick
- https://github.com/cubicdaiya/bms
- https://github.com/kkdai/kmp
- https://github.com/paddie/gokmp
- https://github.com/hillu/go-yara (Yara seems to implement Aho & Corasick under the hood).

Benchmark results ([code here](https://gist.github.com/gwillem/84228ec86953bf5c3ac2d0f01ad017d3)):

```
BenchmarkStringsContains-4         10000        208055 ns/op
BenchmarkBMSSearch-4                1000       1856732 ns/op
BenchmarkPaddieKMP-4                2000       1069495 ns/op
BenchmarkKkdaiKMP-4                 1000       1440147 ns/op
BenchmarkAhocorasick-4              2000        935885 ns/op
BenchmarkYara-4                     1000       1237887 ns/op
```

Then, I benchmarked my practical use case of testing about 1100 signatures (100 regex, 1000 literals) against a 500KB no-match file, for both the native (`strings.Contains` and `regexp`) and the C-based Yara implementations:

```
BenchmarkScanNative-4              2     824328504 ns/op
BenchmarkScanYara-4              300       5338861 ns/op
```

Even though C calls in Go are supposedly expensive, in these "heavy" operations the profit is remarkable. Side observation: it takes Yara just 5 times as much CPU time to match 1100 signatures instead of 1.

Answer (score 2):

Why is Python 3 (24.79s) 4.5 times slower than Go (5.47s)? What results do you get?

**Python**:

```
$ cat contains.py
import time
import re

RUNS = 10000

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # The Complete Works of William Shakespeare by William Shakespeare
    # http://www.gutenberg.org/files/100/100-0.txt
    file = '/home/peter/shakespeare.100-0.txt' # 'data.php'
    with open(file) as fh:
        testString = fh.read()

    def do():
        return "Means to immure herself and not be seen." in testString

    start = time.time()
    for i in range(RUNS):
        _ = do()
    duration = time.time() - start
    print("Python: %.2fs" % duration)
    print(do())
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.5
$ python3 contains.py
Python: 24.79s
True
$
```

**Go**:

```
$ cat contains.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

const (
    runs = 10000
)

func main() {
    // The Complete Works of William Shakespeare by William Shakespeare
    // http://www.gutenberg.org/files/100/100-0.txt
    fname := `/home/peter/shakespeare.100-0.txt` // "data.php"
    testdata := readFile(fname)
    needle := "Means to immure herself and not be seen."
    start := time.Now()

    for i := 0; i < runs; i++ {
        _ = strings.Contains(testdata, needle)

    }
    duration := time.Now().Sub(start)
    fmt.Printf("Go: %.2fs\n", duration.Seconds())

    fmt.Println(strings.Contains(testdata, needle))
    fmt.Println(strings.Index(testdata, needle))

}

func readFile(fname string) string {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fname)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return string(data)
}
$ go version
go version devel +5332b5e75a Tue Jul 31 15:44:37 2018 +0000 linux/amd64
$ go run contains.go
Go: 5.47s
true
5837178
$
```

Comment: Thanks for showing a counter example! Similar results here. It's still puzzling me what makes the difference, so will do more testing.